# Elasticsearch: Perform aggregation on subset of index?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm trying to figure out if/how it's possible to perform aggregation on a subset of documents in an index in elasticsearch. Right now I'm playing around with the significant_terms aggregation like so...

```json
  "aggregations" : {
    "agg" : {
      "significant_terms" : {
        "field" : "contents"
      }
    }
  }
```

Can I limit the documents the aggregation is performed on? I was looking at the filter aggregation but I get empty buckets when trying to use it.

```json
  "aggs" : {
    "aggs2" : {
      "filter": {
        "ids": {
          "values": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "agg" : {
          "significant_terms" : {
            "field" : "contents"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Can I do this, and if so what is the format for the body?

Thanks

EDIT: The example above and the one Val gave me gives me the documents and an empty aggregation response.

```json
  "aggregations": {
    "agg": {
      "doc_count": 6,
      "bg_count": 1111,
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply add your filter to the query section:

```
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": [
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "agg": {
      "significant_terms": {
        "field": "contents"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try this my buckets field array in my aggregation is empty

Comment: What kind of ids do your documents have?

Comment: They are integers right now like in your example. The response has the 6 documents, but the aggregations section has 0 buckets.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I need to assign a min_doc_count. Still figuring out what that minimum should be based on the number of values I provide.